# Photoshop/Javascript - Will this code help me draw fronts on weather maps?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, javascript

I am a meteorologist.  I use Photoshop to help annotate maps.  One thing I always wanted to do, but couldn't, was draw weather fronts.

Recently I've come across some javascript used by leafletjs to draw fronts.  Does any of what I've seen get me closer to being able to draw a front with a path?  I know Photoshop understands javascript, but not much more.

This is very esoteric.  There are few of you who can help.  Thanks in advance.

[Website example from National Weather Service](http://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/exper/nationalforecastchart/map.php)

[Sample of the code I think describes how to draw a front.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SC5oKj_0szjdL0zUW37jbLVwMI8jMkFb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just out of curiosity why dont you use illustrator, it can do this trivially out fo the box and the results are better.

Comment: It looks like your sample JS is meant for an extension of Leaflet (https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator), which has nothing to do with Photoshop.

Answer (score 4):

No this script snippet does nothing for photoshop, atleast its impossible to say anything without knowing what the functions do. Not all javascript is geared to work with Photoshop API so something meant to work in a browser does not work in phostoshop.

On the otherhand Illustrator is far more suitable for this task and can do this all out of the box, no need to do any scripting. (it is also generally more suitable to make maps)

[image]

**Image 1**: Illustrator knows how to do this directly. Right tool for the right job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't want to bite the hand that tried to feed me, but cold fronts are blue, warm fronts are red.  Fronts move in the direction of the bars/pips and close to no fronts north of the equator move from the east.  The fronts look great otherwise.

Comment: No worries its just a test

Comment: would you be able to upload these brushes for our use? I've got illustrator because i'd like to draw these lines, but I it would be a headache of work learning how to use it just to access these brushes.

Comment: @WilliamSkea Well it took me about a minute each to make them. I didnt see it as very important to store them, sorry. If you ask a question im sure somebody answers on how to do them. Teach a man to fish and all that.